# VBA: Excel crashes at End If

Tags: vba, excel

I know that this function works correctly, however when I attempt to fill-down in my spreadsheet it causes Excel to crash almost immediately. When I go into debug mode it tells me there is an issue at the End If. I believe this is correct, as the End If ends the previous If statement.

```
 Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)

'Update 20150310
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String

xResult = ""
For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = pValue Then
        xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
    End If '<-- crashes here
Next
MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

Comment: Just an FYI, this can be done in Office 365 Excel with the new TEXTJOIN() formula as an array `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(LookupRange = pValue,ResultRange,""))` Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: The `End If` is fine, what is the exact error?  By crash do you mean crash to desktop or a runtime error., if so what is it?

Comment: Running out of RAM?

Comment: How large is the range?  Also are you expecting to only look in the first column? If so limit the range to only the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets limit the loop to only the first column and the used range on that sheet:

```
 Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)

'Update 20150310
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
'resets the range to only the first column and the used range.
'this will limit the cycling to the smallest possible range.
Set pWorkRng = Intersect(pWorkRng.Columns(1), pWorkRng.Parent.UsedRange)

xResult = ""
For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = pValue Then
        xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
    End If 
Next
MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps also change this into an array and use the array from then on..

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I thought of that, but not knowing how the OP is using the formula it makes it hard.  If the OP is not putting the full range of values but only the first column and letting the offset do the work of the 2nd dimension makes it hard to put in an array.

Comment: I believe this worked. For those wondering I was matching up a list of about 525 names with a list of 7000 names, with a role fore each name. I needed to attach those roles to each of the 525 names. Basically on one spreadsheet Bob is a Manager, and on the other sheet Bob can do many roles